# Translate "Serving the country in War and Peace" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What is the phrase "Serving the country in War and Peace" in Latin? I need a translation for a novel I'm writing.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Who is serving the country in this case (you, me, or them), or is it more of an infinitive, _to serve_ and not anyone in specific?

Comment: Related question [translating in war and in peace](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/latin-for-in-war-and-in-peace).

Comment: Dear Adam, I'm looking to use "to serve" as an infinitive. "Serving the country in War and Peace" is a motto I'm using for my novel.

Answer (score 5):

"In war and peace" would literally be *in bello et in pace*. However, there are a number of slightly more fancy idiomatic expressions for this idea (as was discussed in [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/latin-for-in-war-and-in-peace) question a while ago). By far the most common of these is *domi militiaeque*, which means: "at home and in military service."

(I am somewhat partial to the alternative *armatus togatusque*, which is a nice metaphor,  but that could be problematic in a number of ways: the absurdity of the idea of, say, a modern politician wearing a toga, or the problem that it refers only to men -- women wearing togas was associated with prostitution.)

For "country" I would say *res publica*, which refers to the state, and is of course the root of the word "republic." Another possibility would be *civitas*, which more stresses the community of citizens (comes perhaps closer to "serving the people").

For "serving" I choose *navare*. *Servire* would also be possible, but more emphasises the submissive position of a servant.

Combining it all, we get:

> Domi militiaeque rem publicam navare

Note: This is the infinitive form. You might want to choose another verb form depending on context, e.g. as a motto for an institution: *navemus*.

Comment: Going off of Horace, I'd opt for *patria* for "country."

Comment: @cmw Oh yes, that is also very good. A sweet and honourable suggestion from you.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm curious about *navo* (which I didn't know about before!). Almost all the L&S examples show it being used to "exhibit" or "perform" something, and the "service" meaning comes in (apparently) from the stock phrase *navare operam/opus*. The only exception that they cite (and which seems to motivate your example) is one example of *navare rem publicam*--but apparently that's a dubious reading!

Comment: @brianpck I was about to write *rei publicae operam navare*, but the *rem publicam* example jumped at me and looked very fitting. But you are right, usually the serviced party is in the dative and the direct object is the service rendered, or *operam*.

Answer (score 2):

Sebastian's translation is solid and straightforward, but I'll offer a suggestion from a different angle. Why not try an existing Latin phrase?

Horace *Odes* 3.2.13 captures half of the sentiment sweetly:

> Dulce et decorum est pro patria mori

> It is sweet and proper to die for one's country.

You could add the verb *vivere* ("to live"), which although it would ruin the poetry, would capture your meaning well enough, I believe.

> Dulce et decorum est pro patria mori at vivere.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulce_et_decorum_est_pro_patria_mori) that a nineteenth century variant using *vivere* was actually used (by whom? how common? it is unsourced):

> Dulce et decorum est pro patria mori, sed dulcius pro patria vivere.
>
> It is sweet and proper to die for one's country, but sweeter [still] to live for it.

Perhaps your book demands a more straightforward translation, but I think it would be an interesting choice to use it somehow, with the added bonus of a recognizable allusion.